# Stuck with INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `impressions` (`date`, `item_id`, `platform`, `country`) VALUES ('" . $date . "', '" . $item_id . "', '" . $platform . "', '" . $country . "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `impressions` = `impressions` + 1
```

And the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 17
)
```

The array basically consists of item_ids, which I want to insert/update in to the database.

When the query runs, I want it to check to see if there are any rows which are from: today, match the specificed item_id, match the specified platform and match the specified country.

For example:

```
2015-03-05 5 mobile US (new insert)
2015-03-05 2 mobile UK (new insert)
2015-03-05 5 mobile US (this would +1 impression from first one)
2015-03-05 17 desktop US (new insert)
2015-03-06 5 mobile US (this would create a new insert because the date doesn't exist)
```

I also want to pass an array of item_ids, as specified above using IN, to avoid multiple looping.

Right now we are currently doing it like this:

```
$item_ids = array('5', '2', '4', '17');

foreach($item_ids as $id){
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `impressions` WHERE `date` = '" . $date . "' AND `item_id` = '" . $id . "' AND `platform` = '" . $platform . "' AND `country` = '" . $country . "'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($q)){
        $r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
        mysql_query("UPDATE `impressions` SET `impressions` = `impressions` + '1' WHERE `id` = '" . $r['id'] . "'");
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `impressions` (`date`, `item_id`, `platform`, `country`, `impressions`) VALUES('" . $date . "', '" . $id . "', '" . $platform . "', '" . $country . "', '1') ");
    }
}
```

We basically want to convert this huge (and badly coded) loop, into 1 mySQL INSERT/UPDATE query which gets passed an array of item_ids to be used with IN.

I am really confused how I should approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE impressions = impressions + 1`

needs to be

`UPDATE impressions = VALUES(impressions) + 1`

Comment: With this fix will it achieve what I am aiming for?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `impressions` (
    `date`, 
    `item_id`, 
    `platform`, 
    `country`, 
    `impressions`
    ) 
VALUES ( 
    '{$date}', 
    {$id}, 
    '{$platform}', 
    '{$country}', '1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE `impressions` = VALUES(impressions) + 1
```

for this to work, see to it that the table impressions has a primary key to check with.

so that the on duplicate key it will update it

Comment: Thanks for this I will test it. How can we go about adding the IN to it so it does it for all item ids rather than looping through the foreach?

Comment: I am using this, I've also created a unique key to insert/update with, which is: `$key = sha1(date('Y-m-d', time()) . $item['id'] . $platform . $country);` - it is inserting the first time, updating the second time but when impressions reaches 2, it isn't updating anymore.

Comment: @KyleR; sorry, its updating, because the value that he is using is always 1, not the latest value in the impressions.impressions when the query runs.
you need to get the latest value of the impressions and put it in the values impressions; hope you get what i mean